# how do you compare multiple strings in C++

Tags: c++, string, if-statement

Im working on a hw assignment and i got stuck at this part.
heres the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


std::string stringSmallest(std::string s1, std::string s2, std::string s3, std::string s4, std::string s5 );


int main(int argc, char)
{
   std::string sSmallest = stringSmallest("hi", "wassup", "hello", "good","bye");
    printf("strings: %i", sSmallest); 
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}

std::string stringSmallest(std::string s1, std::string s2, std::string s3, std::string s4, std::string s5 ){
    std::string strSmallest = 0;
    if (strSmallest.compare(s1)<0)
        strSmallest = s1;

    if (strSmallest.compare(s2)<0)
        strSmallest = s2;

    if (strSmallest.compare(s3)<0)
        strSmallest = s3;

    if (strSmallest.compare(s4)<0)
        strSmallest = s4;

    if (strSmallest.compare(s5)<0)
        strSmallest = s5;

    return strSmallest;
}
```

what im trying to do is create a string with the smallest string.
smallest = smallest(s1, s2, s3, s4, s5)

Comment: What do you mean by "smallest"?

Comment: smallest in what sense? Shortest? First alphabetically? Also, what part(s) of the standard library are you allowed to use/how much do you have to implement from scratch?

Comment: Note you have to `#include <string>`.

Comment: Is the signature given (i.e. you'll have to pass the strings that way), or are you allowed to pass some STL container or an array as well?

Comment: what i think the hw question means is to find the smallest string by size.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
std::string stringSmallest(std::string s1, std::string s2, std::string s3, std::string s4, std::string s5 )
{
std::string strSmallest = s1;

if (strSmallest.compare(s2)>0)
    strSmallest = s2;

if (strSmallest.compare(s3)>0)
    strSmallest = s3;

if (strSmallest.compare(s4)>0)
    strSmallest = s4;

if (strSmallest.compare(s5)>0)
    strSmallest = s5;

return strSmallest;
}
```

Comment: To OP, according to the documentation for the C++98 standard of compare(string, string), it returns > 0 when the compared string is greater than the argument. So, the function simply starts with s1 as a pivot, and changes whenever it is compared to a lesser string, lexicographically.

Comment: oh okay if i printf the value stored in smallest after the function how can i get back a string rather then a bunch of numbers